# Giving player extra hunger

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there anyway I can give the player more "hunger bars" to have to fill up? I know how to do this for extra hearts, but I don't know how to do it with the hunger bar. This is how you do it for extra hearts:

```
/effect <target> 21 <duration> <amplifier>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In the miecraft code it says that the player can ONLY have 10 "hams" (hunger bars) but you can add saturation buff to prevent the hunger from going down.

Comment: Okay thanks! But how could I make it to down faster over time?

Comment: You can apply the Hunger effect to the player. It will increase the rate at witch the hunger is going down.